# Unobstrusive "ignore" setting not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

This is something of an odd one. There are many questions on SO in regard to setting the `ignore` property for unobtrusive validation's `settings` object.

The scenario: I have a table generated by iterating over a model in MVC and I auto-populate a blank row at the bottom by inserting a blank model at the server side (it's part of the requirements, non-negotiable). I don't want to validate this blank row if the user hasn't touched it but do if they have.

To solve this, I generate the table as normal. Using jquery, I auto mark any blank rows with a class of "blank". I can see this happening only for blank rows in the table by viewing the source.

Now, if in the document.read() call on the client I have;

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
var form = $('form').get(0);
var settings = $.data(form, 'validator').settings;
settings.ignore = ':hidden,.blank';
```

This works just fine. Hitting submit will not trigger validation on blank rows even when I add new ones. However, validation doesn't happen on any of the populated rows apart from the first row.

To solve this, I created a function `reattachValidation()` that is called whenever I add a new row so that validation will trigger for the new rows. The code was modified to:

```
function reattachValidation() {
    var forms = $('form');
    forms.removeData('validator');
    forms.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
    var form = $('form').get(0);
    var settings = $.data(form, 'validator').settings;
    settings.ignore = ':hidden,.blank';
}
```

Now the code above will validate any new rows dynamically added to the table but will also validate the blank rows which still have a class of "blank" on the relevant elements. So I can either not validate blank rows and no new rows OR I can validate all rows including those with elements tagged with "blank".

How can I ignore the blank rows while also validating the new rows with user data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually get this working.

In javascript;

```
$(function() {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
    var form = $("form").get(0);
    var settings = $.data(form, "validator").settings;
    settings.ignore = ":hidden,.blank";
});

// This function will attach any dynamic entity (e.g., a new row in a grid) to the
// MVC unobtrusive validator to be validated at the appropriate time.
// Usage:    $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent(newTableRow);
(function ($) {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent = function (selector) {
        //use the normal unobstrusive.parse method
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(selector);

        //get the relevant form
        var form = $(selector).closest("form");

        //get the collections of unobtrusive validators, and jquery validators
        //and compare the two
        var unobtrusiveValidation = form.data("unobtrusiveValidation");
        var validator = form.validate();

        $.each(unobtrusiveValidation.options.rules, function (elname, elrules) {
            if (validator.settings.rules[elname] == undefined) {
                var args = {};
                $.extend(args, elrules);
                args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname];
                //edit:use quoted strings for the name selector
                $("[name='" + elname + "']").rules("add", args);
            } else {
                $.each(elrules, function (rulename, data) {
                    if (validator.settings.rules[elname][rulename] == undefined) {
                        var args = {};
                        args[rulename] = data;
                        args.messages = unobtrusiveValidation.options.messages[elname][rulename];
                        //edit:use quoted strings for the name selector
                        $("[name='" + elname + "']").rules("add", args);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
})($);
```

Then when adding the new dynamic elements, this was done like so (animation is unnecessary but the call to `parseDynamicContent()` is;

```
selectedTableRow.after(newTableRow);
newTableRow.fadeIn(500, function () {
    // reattach the MVC validation after adding a new row so that we get our client
    // side validation on the data annotations.
    // NOTE: we do this AFTER the fade in animation as by default the validator will
    //       not hook into any hidden elements - which our row is until the animation
    //       completes.
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parseDynamicContent(newTableRow);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ignore to work by adding just one line to your original standard way documented elsewhere on SO. This involves removing submit events bound to the form, with the jquery .off(). The reason this needs to be done is that previous instances of the validator object are bound to submit events, and they are not being updated due to the way javascript closures work.

```
$("form").removeData("validator");
$("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$("form").off("submit.validate"); //new line

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");

$("form").validate().settings.ignore = ":hidden, .blank";
```